# Expresso Store - Pin Payments does not complete checkout

Tags: expresso-store, payment-gateway

I'm using Expresso Store 2.3.1, and trying to get take payments via the Pin Payments gateway using Pin.js. This is near identical to the Stripe.js where a card token is added to the form then the token is posted to the server no the card details.

I have everything working right upto the point that I post the form with the card token to Store. I've demonstrated it working upto this point by disabling the post of the form to the server. When I do this you can clearly see the card token in the hidden input.

But when it posts to the server, I don't get any errors in the console or on the page, and I'm returned to the same checkout page.

I've removed inline errors in case there were any hidden errors I was missing.

Here's the relevant javascript:

```
    // 1. Wait for the page to load
$(function() {

  // 2. Create an API object with your publishable api key, and
  // specifying 'test' or 'live'.
  //
  // Be sure to use your live publishable key with the live api, and
  // your test publishable key with the test api.
  var pinApi = new Pin.Api('pk_tlFaC6Qk0MDp4wdNsa-noQ', 'test');

  var form = $('form.pin'),
      submitButton = form.find(":submit"),
      errorContainer = form.find('.errors'),
      errorList = errorContainer.find('ul'),
      errorHeading = errorContainer.find('h3');

  // 3. Add a submit handler to the form which calls Pin.js to
  // retrieve a card token, and then add that token to the form and
  // submit the form to your server.
  form.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Clear previous errors
    errorList.empty();
    errorHeading.empty();
    errorContainer.hide();

    // Disable the submit button to prevent multiple clicks
    submitButton.attr({disabled: true});

    // Fetch details required for the createToken call to Pin Payments
    var card = {
      number:           $('#cc-number').val(),
      name:             $('#cc-name').val(),
      expiry_month:     $('#cc-expiry-month').val(),
      expiry_year:      $('#cc-expiry-year').val(),
      cvc:              $('#cc-cvc').val(),
      address_line1:    $('#address-line1').val(),
      address_line2:    $('#address-line2').val(),
      address_city:     $('#address-city').val(),
      address_state:    $('#address-state').val(),
      address_postcode: $('#address-postcode').val(),
      address_country:  $('#address-country').val()

    };

    // Request a token for the card from Pin Payments
    pinApi.createCardToken(card).then(handleSuccess, handleError).done();
  });

  function handleSuccess(card) {
    // Add the card token to the form
    //
    // Once you have the card token on your server you can use your
    // private key and Charges API to charge the credit card.
    $('<input>')
      .attr({type: 'hidden', id: 'payment_token', name: 'payment[token]'})

      .val(card.token)
      .appendTo(form);
      console.log(card.token);

    // Resubmit the form to the server
    //
    // Only the card_token will be submitted to your server. The
    // browser ignores the original form inputs because they don't
    // have their 'name' attribute set.
    form.get(0).submit();
  }

  function handleError(response) {
    errorHeading.text(response.error_description);

    if (response.messages) {
      $.each(response.messages, function(index, paramError) {
        $('<li>')
          .text(paramError.param + ": " + paramError.message)
          .appendTo(errorList);
      });
    }

    errorContainer.show();

    // Re-enable the submit button
    submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
  };
});
```

And here's my checkout code:

```
      {exp:store:checkout
                form_class="form-horizontal pure-form pure-form-stacked pin"
                return="checkout/order/ORDER_HASH"
                payment_method="Pin"
               }

                {if no_items}
                    {redirect="checkout"}
                {/if}

                <input type="hidden" id="address_line-1" value="{billing_address1}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="address_line-2" name="{billing_address2}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="address_city" name="{billing_city}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="address_state" name="{billing_state}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="address_postcode" name="{billing_postcode}" />
                <input type="hidden" id="address_country" name="{billing_country}" />
            <div class="pure-g">
                <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-2">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Payment</legend>

                {if error:payment_method}
                    <div class="pure-control-group">
                        <div class="alert alert-error">{error:payment_method}</div>
                    </div>
                {/if}

                <div class='errors'>
                    <h3></h3>
                    <ul></ul>
                </div>

                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cc-number">Card No</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="cc-number" value="4200000000000000" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cc-name">Name</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="cc-name"  value="TEST USER" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ontrol-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cc-expiry-month">Expiry</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select id="cc-expiry-month" style="width:auto">
                            <option value="01">01</option>
                            {exp_month_options}
                        </select>
                        <select id="cc-expiry-year"  style="width:auto">
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
                            {exp_year_options}
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="pure-control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="cc-cvc">CSC</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <input type="text" id="cc-cvc" value="123" class="input-mini" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <a href="{path='checkout/step2'}" class="pure-button">Back</a>
        <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Place Order" class="pure-button pure-button-primary" />
    </div>

{/exp:store:checkout}
```

This one really has be beat. While I think I might be seeing an issue where Pin.js intercepts every form submission and get's  a new token for every form submission, if I disable Pin.js and manually add the token that was previously issued, it still won't give a meaningful response after post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this working but only after two hours of debugging.

- Pin.net requires address-line1, address-city
- Using form.get(0).submit() will not work if you submit button has name="submit"
- Store redirects you to the same page if no POST['submit'] is found. Your submit button must be named "submit" e.g. name="submit"
- If you disable (disabled="disabled") your submit button it will not be "POSTED", so Store will redirect you to the same page

So instead of using form.submit() i used a click handler on the submit button.

Here is my example code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn.pin.net.au/pin.v2.js'></script>

    <script>
    // 1. Wait for the page to load
    $(function() {

        // 2. Create an API object with your publishable api key, and
        // specifying 'test' or 'live'.
        //
        // Be sure to use your live publishable key with the live api, and
        // your test publishable key with the test api.
        var pinApi = new Pin.Api('pk_kmzTxiNh25A6lU1sZIgmqQ', 'test');

        var form = $('form.pin');
        var submitButton = form.find(":submit");
        var errorContainer = form.find('.errors');
        var errorList = errorContainer.find('ul');
        var errorHeading = errorContainer.find('h3');

        // 3. Add a submit handler to the form which calls Pin.js to
        // retrieve a card token, and then add that token to the form and
        // submit the form to your server.
        submitButton.click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // Clear previous errors
            errorList.empty();
            errorHeading.empty();
            errorContainer.hide();

            // Disable the submit button to prevent multiple clicks
            submitButton.attr({disabled: true});

            // Fetch details required for the createToken call to Pin Payments
            var card = {
                number:           $('#payment_card_no').val(),
                name:             $('#payment_name').val(),
                expiry_month:     $('#payment_exp_month').val(),
                expiry_year:      $('#payment_exp_year').val(),
                cvc:              $('#payment_csc').val(),
                address_line1:    $('#address-line1').val(),
                address_line2:    $('#address-line2').val(),
                address_city:     $('#address-city').val(),
                address_state:    $('#address-state').val(),
                address_postcode: $('#address-postcode').val(),
                address_country:  $('#address-country').val()
            };

            // Request a token for the card from Pin Payments
            pinApi.createCardToken(card).then(handleSuccess, handleError).done();

            return false;
        });

        function handleSuccess(card) {
            // Add the card token to the form
            //
            // Once you have the card token on your server you can use your
            // private key and Charges API to charge the credit card.
            $('<input>')
                .attr({type: 'hidden', name: 'payment[token]'})
                .addClass('card_token')
                .val(card.token)
                .appendTo(form);

            // Turn off the click handler and click it
            submitButton.off('click').val('processing...').removeAttr('disabled').click();
        }

        function handleError(response) {
            // Empty the card token
            form.find('.card_token').val('');

            errorHeading.text(response.error_description);

            if (response.messages) {
                $.each(response.messages, function(index, paramError) {
                    $('<li>')
                        .text(paramError.param + ": " + paramError.message)
                        .appendTo(errorList);
                });
            }

            errorContainer.show();

            // Re-enable the submit button
            submitButton.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>


{exp:store:checkout
    form_class="form-horizontal pure-form pure-form-stacked pin"
    return="store_example/order/ORDER_HASH"
    error_handling="inline"
    payment_method="Pin"
}

    {if no_items}
        {redirect="store_example/checkout"}
    {/if}

    <div class='errors' style='display:none'>
        <h3></h3>
        <ul></ul>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="address_line-1" value="{billing_address1}">
    <input type="hidden" id="address_line-2" value="{billing_address2}">
    <input type="hidden" id="address_city" value="{billing_city}">
    <input type="hidden" id="address_state" value="{billing_state}">
    <input type="hidden" id="address_postcode" value="{billing_postcode}">
    <input type="hidden" id="address_country" value="{billing_country}">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Payment</legend>

        <label>Card No</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_card_no" value="">

        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_name" value="">

        <label>Expiry</label>
        <select id="payment_exp_month" style="width:auto">
            <option value=""></option>
            {exp_month_options}
        </select>
        <select id="payment_exp_year" style="width:auto">
            <option value=""></option>
            {exp_year_options}
        </select>

        <label>CSC</label>
        <input type="text" id="payment_csc" value="" class="input-mini">
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Place Order">

{/exp:store:checkout}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel, I'll need to pickup this project to test again in a few days, makes sense though. I had already figured out the submit button name but didn't work when I tested it, now I know it didn't work as I was missing half the solution. Thanks for your help on this, I'll post back and accept once I've tested it all.

Comment: Took me ages to come back to this one, I've now tested and working perfectly. Thanks again.